# How can a validator comfirm a poh from the leader?

Tags: validator

The validator don't have the fully data .how can a validator comfirm a poh from the leader? What if the leader is evil and make some fake transactions? And why don't use just pos instead poh? Does the poh is really necessary? Where I can find some info about these questions as I can not find the info in the doc?

Answer (score 2):

> The validator don't have the fully data .how can a validator comfirm a
> poh from the leader?

The validator is expected to have a trusted starting point of ledger state with which they can build off of (i.e. the hash of state they believe is good). Once they have this, PoH can be verified by performing the hashing on the validator and comparing with the leader PoH entries in the block.

> What if the leader is evil and make some fake transactions?

What is meant by fake transactions here? The downstream validators will ensure transactions are performed with valid accounts that are funded and that transactions are signed by owners of those accounts.

> And why don't use just pos instead poh? Does the poh is really necessary?

PoS is important for things like voting and prioritization of traffic. PoH is important for verifying the passage of time. Different consensus mechanisms for very different purposes.

Verifying passage of time is important for synchronization between validators as well as transactions.

Because there is an agreed upon leader schedule, a malicious leader that is trying to propose a block at the same time as the “real” leader is forced to complete all the necessary PoH ticks to prove the correct passage of time has taken place to get to its leader slot. This should be impossible to complete faster than the hashing operations can actually complete and thus allows (forces) block producers to stay synchronized.

Regarding transactions, we can ensure rough time ordering of transactions using PoH + including blockhashes in transactions. The blockhash ensures the transaction must have come after the block where that blockhash appeared. PoH ensures it must have come before the time it took to complete the trailing ticks (because the transactions become part of the hash, so trying to insert after the fact would necessitate recomputing all of the hashes serially).

> Where I can find some info about these questions as I can not find the
> info in the doc?

The [solana docs](https://docs.solana.com/cluster/synchronization), [medium](https://medium.com/solana-labs/proof-of-history-explained-by-a-water-clock-e682183417b8), and the [white paper](https://solana.com/solana-whitepaper.pdf) are all good resources for understanding the basics architecture/design choices on Solana

Comment: hello, many thanks for your help.
1. the validator has a  a trusted starting point of ledger state ,and the transactions can be confirmed to be sent by the real owner ,so when a validator get a transaction and execute it successfully, then it can be trusted, is that right?
2.PoH is important for verifying the passage of time, why should we verify the passage of time? what is the advanteges of poh? what will happen if we just use pos like ethereum?

Comment: 1.) Yes, that’s right.
2.) Verifying passage of time is important for synchronization between validators as well as transactions.

Added more info to original answer to address 2 more in depth

Comment: Does the solana validator execute all the transactions in a block or a part of the block? If all the block will the confirm slow? Will it collect the whole block before execute the transactions in the block?

Comment: Thanks for your patience

Comment: The validator is expected to execute all of the transaction in a block. There are limits on resource consumption (e.g. CU limits, data limits, etc.) to ensure block time can fit in 400ms slot time with reasonable HW. It can start executing transactions before collecting an entire block (streaming fashion)

Comment: So， assuming that a block has multiple parts, if the second part is received, do we need to wait for the data from the first part to arrive before executing the second part? does a shred contains a transaction or a batch of transactions?

Comment: The current code will wait for the first part to arrive before executing the second part. A shred can contain multiple transactions (however many can fit into an entry of 1280B)

Comment: Hello , is the leader send all the transactions after the whole block is completed? or is the leader just send the batch of transactions when it processed a batch of transactions? So,will the leader process the transactions before the slot?

Comment: If the leader process the transactions before the slot, how can he link to  the poh from the previous leader?

Comment: And does solana use gpu in the bank stage? if not how does it execute more than cpu cores transactions parallel?

Comment: The leader will stream the transactions to downstream validators after processing. It will not wait for block completion. The leader does not process transactions before the slot begins. It will have the blockhash for the parent slot it builds off. Yes, it is possible to use GPU for verification of PoH and entries. It is also possible to use CPU. Concurrent processing would be limited to CPU cores in this case

Comment: And how does the transactions send to the leader? As I know the leader use turbine to send out blocks,so does the transactions send to leader level by level in turbine?If not ,who will the leader connect to? Is the leader randomly pick one node to connect?

Comment: @user2712 - Would you mind creating a new question for this?

Comment: yes ,this is . https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/6329/how-does-the-transactions-send-to-the-leader @BW-Solana